# How to share assets across multiple dockerfiles without copying?

Tags: docker

Is there some simple way of doing this properly without copying and removing all caches?

buildkit offers only solutions for single dockerfile afaik

Comment: Please add more details. What do you mean by assets? Provide some examples.

Comment: An image should generally be self-contained, so you’ll need to `COPY` content into multiple images if they all need it.  You should not normally need to disable Docker’s image caching.

Comment: assets is anything that can be stored on disk. ANYTHING. So that would be disk access. 

I don't mind copying but then all docker examples should start with mkdir and copies in an makefile. 

I actually think this would be best: all docker examples should be pure makefiles + Dockerfiles. No dockerhub allowed. Everything local except for internals of the app of course.